# How to hide a GTK window in Python before call or os.system

Tags: python, application-development, gtk3, pygtk

So, I'm depeloping a Python/GTK app which, after showing an assistant, it hides the assistant's window and runs an external app. The problem is that `window.hide()` doesn't works if, after the command, there's an app call using `os.system()` or `call()`. When the call is done, the window seems to hang and it doesn't disappears until all the calls are done. So... what can be done?

Comment: We are making a client/server app, and we have some troubles with gtk, it seams to lock our thread in the Gtk.main(). So we might be interested about using your solution, but where did you put those lines ?

Comment: Yep, I had the same problem with an app which I've done. Let me check...

Comment: OK, it seems to fix the hanged thread error. Just insert it before the code which causes the problem, and done! :)

Comment: Wait... I'm not sure, try it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time googling possible solutions, I've found this simple answer, which waits to GTK until it finished all its working tasks. You may think that makes the app slower, but the difference is almost unexistent.

This workaround can be used with **any** version of Python. It works with PyGTK and with GTK+3 (with GTK+3, change `gtk` per `Gtk`... :P )

```
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration()
```

Just add this before the code which causes the problem... and done! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my applications I tend to replace `os.system()` and `subprocess.call()` with `subprocess.Popen` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/636570/2372604).

Comment: I've been using `subprocess.Popen` recently and it's really delightful. If only I knew back then!

Answer (score 0):

Using openSUSE Leap 15.5, Python 3.6.15 and GTK 4.6.9 here.

In short, the idea is: hide the window by calling [`Gtk.Window.hide()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Widget.hide.html), then start a thread using [`threading.Timer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) (non-blocking). In that thread, run the external app with [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (blocking) then show the window again with [`Gtk.Window.show()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Widget.show.html).

Here is a complete working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import sys
import threading
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk


class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.set_default_size(600, 250)
        self.set_title('MyApp')

        self.box1 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.set_child(self.box1)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label='Launch')
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)
        self.box1.append(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, button):
        self.hide()
        t = threading.Timer(1, self.launch)
        t.start()

    def launch(self):
        subprocess.run(['gnome-calculator'])
        self.show()


class MyApp(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)

    def on_activate(self, app):
        self.main_window = MainWindow(application=app)
        self.main_window.present()


app = MyApp(application_id='com.example.MyApp')
app.run(sys.argv)
```

These may be useful:

- [Taiko's GTK4 Python tutorial](https://github.com/Taiko2k/GTK4PythonTutorial)
- [How To Use subprocess to Run External Programs in Python 3  | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-subprocess-to-run-external-programs-in-python-3)
- [The subprocess Module: Wrapping Programs With Python – Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-subprocess/)
- [An Intro to Threading in Python – Real Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#timer)